# Cardioid calculus: Problems with calculating the perimeter

Tags: calculus

I am having several problems with calculus dealing with cardioid so I guess I will ask several questions. This is the first one. I should get the formula for the perimeter of the cardioid given by: $r=a(1-\sin \phi)$ by using integration in polar coordinates $(r,\phi)$. My idea was to represent infinitesimal arc legth by the following formula: $ds= \sqrt{r^2+(dr/d\phi)^2}d\phi$, to integrate this for $\phi$ from  $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$ and to multiply result with 2 in order to get the entire perimeter. Now, after expressing this as a function of $\phi$, I get integral $$\int_{\phi=-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{2a^2- (2a^2)\sin \phi}\,d\phi$$  (which i will multiply by two in the end). Now, extracting $a*\sqrt2$ in front of the integral, the integrand that remains is $\sqrt{1-\sin \phi}$. I solved this by substituting $t=\tan(\phi/2)$, and then boundaries of integration become $\tan(-\pi/4)$ and $\tan (\pi/4)$ ie. $t$ moves from $-1$ to $1$. After substituting in $d\phi$ and in the integrand I get $$\int_{t=-1}^1\frac{(1-t)dt}{(t^2+1)^{3/2}}.$$  This one dissolves into 2 integrals, the second one (whose integrand is $t/(t^2+1)^{3/2}$ having antisymmetric integrand and symmetric boundaries), reducing to zero. So I am left with the integral 
$$\int_{t=-1}^1 (t^2+1)^{-3/2}dt.$$
I solve this by substituting $t=\tan U$ which gives integral $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\cos U\, dU$. When I solve this I get $\sqrt2$. After multiplying it with a$\sqrt2$ I extracted before and again with 2 in order to get the perimeter, the result is 4a. However, I found out that the result should be 8a. I haven't succeed in figuring out where I lost this factor of 2. If someone sees where I went wrong, help would be appreciated.

Comment: I TeXified it a bit. Completing soon. Please check that it looks all right. You could also use paragraph breaks every now and then to enhance legibility.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen , thanks very much. It looks great and formulas are correct.

Comment: It will probably be worth your while to learn a little LaTeX. There are links here somewhere to pointers (in the FAQ?). If you really wanted to use $\phi$ in place of $F$, you can go and edit the question again. The LaTeX-keyword `\phi` will output $\phi$.

Comment: And if you prefer a different looking Greek letter there, then `\varphi` gives you $\varphi$ :-)

Comment: Thank you for the assistence, Jyrki. I will learn LaTeX :) As for the\phi, that's exactly what I wanted so I'll fix it now :)

Comment: A different way to attack integrating $\sqrt{1-\sin\varphi}$ uses this helpful trig identity: $$\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\left( 1 - \cos\theta \right)$$ Setting $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi$, this becomes $$\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\varphi}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\sin \varphi\right)$$

Comment: Thanks, blue, Interrestingly, using your substitution gives me the correct result, so I definitely made a mistake in my derivation somewhere.

Comment: @Blue: please put your comment in as an answer so that this may be taken off the unanswered queue.

Comment: @Ron Gordon, Well, Blue's comment hasn't actually answered my question because I still don't know what I did wrong :) It was a very useful info about relevant substitution, though :)

Comment: @Blue: Thanks for the note! I tried to accept it now and I got the message that I could accept it in 18 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my mistake. After substituting  $t=\tan(\phi/2)$ I mistakenly calculated  $d\phi$=$\frac{dt}{t^2+1}$ while $d\phi$ is actually that value multiplied by 2.